# Key is a duplicate in ./composer.json

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

Am trying structure my app in  such a way that all my models will be in a dedicated directory(in my case Classified). I created the directory with Laravel app directory and added it to my my composer.json file. Below is the structure of my composer.json file:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Classified\\": "app/",
        "Classified\\": "app/Classified"
    }
},
```

Then I run composer dump-autoload in my terminal but I keep getting "Key Classified\ is a duplicate in ./composer.json at line 29
" and when I tried viewing my app in the browser i get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class App\Http\Kernel does not exist' in /home/vagrant/Workspace/codulabproducts/classified/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 736.

Line 29 in my composer.json file is

```
"Classified\\": "app/Classified"
```

I don't know what am doing wrong because I have followed these steps in my other project and everything went well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have duplicated keys in your **psr-4** mapping. It is supposed to define the root folder for given namespace and a namespace cannot have multiple roots.

Remove one of the mappings for **Classified\** namespace.

Comment: Now I get it. I changed the second mapping and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 10):

You can define more than one directory for a namespace prefix. But in that case the value for the key must be a list and not a string (see [the second example in the documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4)):

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Classified\\": ["app/", "app/Classified"]
        }
    }
}
```